# Any way to rescue when linux run out of memory, except resetting machine?

Tags: linux, shell, linux-kernel

When machine is under extremely heavy load, some serivce app might eat up all memory and swap is fully used as well.
Linux will start kill processes itself, usually shell has been killed and screen is scrolling madly when you find that issue.

Here is my log when machine out of memory (similar error repeat make screen scrolled)

```
[11988288.358984] Mem-info:
[11988288.358987] DMA per-cpu:
[11988288.358992] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[11988288.358997] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[11988288.359002] DMA32 per-cpu:
[11988288.359006] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 171
[11988288.359012] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 180
[11988288.359019] Active:490848 inactive:2177 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
[11988288.359021]  free:3441 slab:3328 mapped:20 pagetables:0 bounce:0
[11988288.359032] DMA free:8084kB min:44kB low:52kB high:64kB active:1908kB inactive:1732kB present:16160kB pages_scanned:9935 all_unreclaimable? yes
[11988288.359041] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 2012 2012 2012
[11988288.359052] DMA32 free:5680kB min:5716kB low:7144kB high:8572kB active:1961484kB inactive:6976kB present:2060400kB pages_scanned:972601 all_unreclaimable? no
[11988288.359063] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[11988288.359071] DMA: 13*4kB 16*8kB 16*16kB 17*32kB 25*64kB 29*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 8084kB
[11988288.359093] DMA32: 108*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 2*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 5680kB
[11988288.359112] 66 total pagecache pages
[11988288.359117] Swap cache: add 603678, delete 603677, find 189475/220048
[11988288.359123] Free swap  = 0kB
[11988288.359126] Total swap = 1048568kB
[11988288.372922] 526336 pages of RAM
[11988288.372937] 11131 reserved pages
[11988288.372942] 451075 pages shared
[11988288.372946] 1 pages swap cached
[11988288.372952] Out of memory: kill process 14767 (exim4) score 4076 or a child
[11988288.372998] Killed process 14767 (exim4)
```

My questions

1. Is there anything can be done when you wanna rescue such memory-run-out machine? (except resetting machine)?
2. Any system config can be set to make Linux kernel stronger and keep alive when memory shortage?

Comment: Err.. add more RAM and/or increase the size of the pagefile?

Comment: yes, it is. that is usually what I do. I just can not help to wonder is there any "magic" way exist to handle out-of-memory, so raise the question here.

Comment: Cant be done anything, even I face this issue with my ec2 ubuntu instances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can help the OOM killer choose it's target by adjusting a value for each process :

```
echo some_value > /proc/pid/oom_score_adj
```

This value is added to the score calculated by the oom killer to selects it's next victim. It can be used to either protect some processes if a negative value is used, or for the opposite ie increasing the likelyhood for a process to be targeted by the OOM killer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is useful to make specified process protected.